# how to share Google cloud bill between apps

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want some apps to use some resources on GCP, all apps must use the same account.
but I want to know how much each app consumes.
in another word, I want to be able to generate a separate bill for each app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels can be used to group the resources related to each application and using the same labels we can find out the resource utilization and we can generate separate billing reports for each application. All you need to do is send your billing data to a big query and query the data using the labels which you created for grouping the resources. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/cost-management/use-labels-to-gain-visibility-into-gcp-resource-usage-and-spending) outlines the concept of labeling and getting resource utilization and bills using labels follow it for more information.

Comment: nice info, I will try it.  anyway, I'm giving it the "accepted answer" because it is augmented with the correct part in the docs.  thank you @Kranthiveer Dontineni,